# jQuery: Function not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to execute a function twice, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/g6PLu/3/

**Javascript**

```
function truncate() {
    $(this).addClass('closed').children().slice(0,2).show().find('.truncate').show();
}

$('div').each(truncate);

$('.truncate').click(function() {

if ($(this).parent().hasClass('closed')) {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('closed').addClass('open').children().show();
}

else if ($(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
    $('div').each(truncate);
    $(this).show();
}

});
```

The problem is on line 15, where I call `$('div').each(truncate);` the second time. For some reason it doesn't seem to be executing. Any ideas?

Comment: It's running every time, but since the `div` is already visible, `show()` won't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating a simple task. I'd take advantage of the classes to show/hide stuff with CSS (you're adding the classes but not using them!).

Check out this simpler version:

**Relevant CSS**

```
.closed p { display: none; }
.closed p:nth-child(2) { display: block; }
```

**JS**

```
$('div').addClass('closed');
$('.truncate').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div').toggleClass('closed');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g6PLu/9/

Comment: Note: `nth-child(x)` won't work on IE8 and lower. If you need the code to work in older browsers, add a class to the `<p>` that should always be visible.

Answer (score 1):

When you call show, the `<p>` changes to `<p style="display: block; ">` that's why, you need to call hide or remove that style part

is this the spected behavior?

```
else if ($(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('open').addClass('closed').children().hide();
    $('div').each(truncate);
    $(this).show();
}
```